# monotouch UICollectionView is giving null reference error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, nib

I am new to monotouch. I have a `UICollectionViewCell` .xib file where I have image and label set. In another viewcontroller which is like

```
public partial class TestViewController : UICollectionViewController {

    public TestViewController (UICollectionViewLayout layout) : 
        base ("TestViewController", null)
    {
        CollectionView.RegisterNibForCell (UINib.FromName (
            "imagesCollectionViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle), imageCellId);
    }
}
```

it gives null reference exception at `CollectionView.RegisterNibForCell (UINib.FromName ("imagesCollectionViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle), imageCellId);`

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [1] the `CollectionView` property is `null` at this point of time - i.e. when inside the constructor of your `TestViewController` type.

It is likely set (by iOS) to a valid (non-null) value later (e.g. when `ViewDidAppear` is called). In that case you should move your call to `RegisterNibForCell` later in the execution.

[1] you can use the debugger to see the values of any fields/properties.

Comment: if I move that RegisterNibForCell to ViewDidLoad and put a breakpoint, it never comes to ViewDidLoad